# error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: typescript

```
class Car {
    engineName: string;
    gears: number;
    private speed: number;

    constructor(speed: number) {
        this.speed = speed || 0;
    }

    accelerate(): void {
        this.speed++;
    }

    throttle():void {
        this.speed--;
    }

    getSpeed():void {
        console.log(this.speed);
    }

    static numberOfWheels(): number {
        return 4;
    }
}


// Instantiate (create) an object from a class

let car = new Car(5);
```

Compiling this Type Script code within Visual Studio Code 1.18.1
On the last statement, I get the error message.
**"error TS1005: ';' expected"**

Why? "let car = new Car(5);" should be a correct TS statement.

The "TSC -V" command renders: "Version 1.0.3.0"
"npm view typescript version" renders: 2.6.2

Comment: The error indicates that a `;` is expected *instead* of what you put there, not anything about that statement itself. You probably need a `;` after the `class` declaration.

Comment: Is it possible that the class should end with `};` ?

Comment: Your `tsc` is pointing to either an outdated global or local version of typescript. If you are running windows see if there is an old `path` variable that is pointing to an outdated directory. Either way that is likely the culprit because the syntax above is OK. *You do not need an `;` at the end of the class and you do not need an `export` on the class.*

Comment: @Igor answer was the one that proved to be the correct one. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tsc` is pointing to either an outdated global or local version of typescript. If you are running windows see if there is an old path variable that is pointing to an outdated directory. Either way that is likely the culprit because the syntax above is OK.

*You do not need an ; at the end of the class and you do not need an export on the class.*